# for if/elseif loop not working in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I want to calculate the sum of the following logic below. Basically add one to numTrade whenever the number switches from 0 to -1 or 1, and also when number switches between 1 and -1. Treat consecutive elements as 0, such that (0, 1, 1, 1) is counted as 1 and (1,0,-1,1) is counted as 2.

numTrade should return total of 4, but instead it returns 3. Can someone please explain why?

```
numTrade<-0

numUnits<-c(0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1)

for(i in 2:length(numUnits)){
  if(numUnits[i]>0 & numUnits[i-1]<0){
    numTrade<-numTrade+1
  }
  else if(numUnits[i]<0 & numUnits[i-1]>0){
    numtrade<-numTrade+1
  }
    else if(numUnits[i]!=0 & numUnits[i-1]==0){
      numTrade<-numTrade+1
    } 
      else {
        numTrade<-numTrade+0
      }
  print(numTrade)
}
```

Comment: (0,-1) should add one as well...

Comment: The loop doesn't recognize (-1,1) for some reason if you check out the `print(numTrade)`...

Comment: The last else if statement should take care of it... `else if(numUnits[i]!=0 & numUnits[i-1]==0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check following code,

```
numTrade<-0

numUnits<-c(0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1)

for(i in 2:length(numUnits)){
  print( sprintf("numUnits[I-1]: numUnits[I]: %d -> %d ", numUnits[i-1],  numUnits[i]))

  if((numUnits[i-1]<0 & numUnits[i]>0) | numUnits[i-1]>0 & numUnits[i]<0  ){
    print( "Match for between 1 to -1")
    numTrade<-numTrade+1
  }
 else if( numUnits[i-1]==0 & numUnits[i]!=0 ){
    print( "Match for 0 to 1/-1")
    numTrade<-numTrade+1
  } 
  else {
    numTrade<-numTrade+0
  }
} 
print( numTrade)
```

Here we need to check 2 conditions, one in between 1 to -1 and other is 0 to 1/-1.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But can you explain how come when I ran 2 separate conditions like in my original if statement it stopped working?

Comment: you did one mistake in your second condition for variable name "numtrade" but excepted is "numTrade" (check T is in capital)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "vectorized" equivalent which should do what you expect:

```
numUnits <- c(0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1)

absDiff <- abs(diff(numUnits))
numTrade <- sum((head(numUnits, -1) == 0 & absDiff == 1) | absDiff == 2)
print(numTrade)
```

Result is 4.

### Edit

`for` loops are notoriously slow in R. In this case, the vector version is about 50 times faster (measured with the `microbenchmark` package).